# Where can I get the current version of RSMacAccessUtility?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

Have a slight dilemma, I left a company a couple of years ago and they used RSMacAccessUtility to convert all MSOffice files to .xml and you needed the utility to re-open the files.

Fast forward to current day and I need to go and look at these documents, the issues is that Mac OS is now Catalina and the original utility does not work with Catalina.

I have tried the obvious paths (Google, Youtube etc.) but can find it, then I tried to find out how to convert from .xml back to .pptx .doc etc .... No joy.

Can you help, pleeeeease?

Comment: have you seen this article, explains 7-zip and burning the .dmg files to CD-ROM? "__How to Open DMG Files on Windows__" https://itstillworks.com/open-dmg-files-windows-5844394.html

Comment: Is it SEE-RS Access Utility(RSMacAccessUtility.dmg)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the installer/dmg but it won't run on Catalina, then your only real options are

1. Find someone not yet on Catalina who can do this for you, or
2. Set up a virtual machine running Mojave or older.